# How to trigger a <input type="file"> element using jquery

Tags: jquery, input

Is there a way to trigger the click even of :

```
<input id="test" type="file">
```

?

Answer (score 5):

I was looking for the same thing and found an answer at
[trigger file upload dialog using javascript/jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502612/trigger-file-upload-dialog-using-javascript-jquery)
and a running example is at
http://jsfiddle.net/CSvjw/

it simply does

```
$('#test').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 2):

Dont use **display:none** or **visibility:hidden** initially in the css

In **Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#test').hide(); 
});
```

Comment: that really helped me ..... awesome....i was not able to figure out why it is working ....but it is work...:)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to trigger the upload window programmatically, however if you just want to hide the ugly "choose a file"-button and inputfield, there is a simple solution.

Just hide the input using any old technique and add a label refering to it. You can then style the label any way you want. Clicking the label will trigger the upload window.

For example:

```html
<input id="test" type="file" style="display: none" />
<label for="test" class="make-it-look-like-a-button">Upload</label>
```

Comment: I was using the click trigger myself until I found a problem. If you use the click trigger on a dynamic element for some reason it won't load the uploads into the input. Anyway I took your advice and styled a label as a button and it works, even on dynamic. I know the guy is saying how to do this in jQuery, but really this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to trigger it programmatically for **security** reasons. You got to click it explicitly.

Comment: See Khaled's comment below. All you have to do is trigger a click in JavaScript of the file input.

Comment: Prefilling an input type file is definitely not possible because of security considerations (stealing a user's files without his consent or knowledge), but opening it is allowed by browser, and [can be done like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12881646/216084).

Answer (score 0):

Not possible (security reasons).

Answer (score -1):

No, there isn't, and this is a good thing as it would be extremely annoying for the user. Whether a user wants to upload some file is in is control only, personally I would hate a site automatically sticking an Open Dialog into my nose when I visit it.