# js - set hotkeys on upload files

Tags: javascript, upload, hotkeys

For example, I have an input tag like:

```
<input type="file" id="upload" multiple="true">
```

Is this possible to choose files by setting a hotkey instead of clicking on input element?

Comment: possible duplicate of [trigger file upload dialog using javascript/jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502612/trigger-file-upload-dialog-using-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).on("keydown", function(e){
    e = e || window.event;
    var keyCode = event.keyCode;   // code of the key pressed

    if(e.ctrlKey){             // if control key is pressed
        if(keyCode == 13){     // if current key is "enter" key
            $("input[type='file']").trigger("click");  // trigger click event
        }
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/vmjr5/)**

[Here's a list of all key codes](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes).

Comment: I've found out the problem. Just because It triggers all `input[type='file']` on my site :). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

using `document.keyup`
check out this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Karim_AG/PcR7v/1/), try clicking ctrl + i