# Show input file dialog on load?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, file-upload, file-io

I'm making a dialog for changing an image. Instead of having the user to click the file input field I want it to be brought up immediately. The input field is simply a:

```
<input type="file">
```

Is there a way to display it when page is loaded?

Bonus points if there is an angular way of doing it.

Comment: This is really close to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502612/trigger-file-upload-dialog-using-javascript-jquery. You can modify the techniques described there to use native JS instead of jQuery for a similar effect.

Comment: Or you could use an modal, and it would solve your problem.

Comment: some browsers want a human to click the file input, so a .click() won't work...

Comment: because of security issues it's forbidden

Comment: Triggering it by code is forbidden?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210643/in-javascript-can-i-make-a-click-event-fire-programmatically-for-a-file-input) only Internet Explorer allows for programmatic opening of the File Upload dialog.
So the short answer is no, there is no way to automatically open the File Upload dialog on page load.

The long answer that you might consider is that you can show it when the user clicks on [anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928386/jquery-trigger-click-not-working-on-safari-browsers-in-mac-ipad-iphone/8991665#8991665).
The fact that you prefer an AngularJS solution tells us that you are writing a Single Page Application. Also, I don't think you need to show the File Upload dialog when the app first loads. You most likely need it to show *after* some user interaction - after the user clicks on something. That something, using the an AngularJS directive from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571001/file-upload-using-angularjs), could look like anything but be a file input. On click (the same user interaction) you can also switch to another route in your AngularJS app, effectively simulating a user navigating to another page and automatically presenting him the File Upload dialog.