# How to click an input (type=file) on onload event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Current [html](/questions/tagged/html) / [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) code...

```js
function myfunction() {
    alert("hello");
    document.getElementById('file').click();
}
```

```html
<body onload="myfunction();">
    <input type="file" id="file" />
</body>
```

Now `alert` is displayed, but file is not clicked on `onload` event but if we change the event to `onclick`, the `alert` is shown as well as file is also clicked.

Comment: Are you trying to open the file dialog?

Comment: Why do you need to fire up file browser `onload`? I smell something fishy here ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24250877/show-input-file-dialog-on-load

Answer (score 1):

Based on the security model of the modern browsers this is not possible.  The `click` function will not work until the user has interacted with the page.  The best I could come up with is the [`onfocus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/focus) event which requires the user to do very little to interact with the page.

Try this...

```js
function myfunction() {
    alert("hello");
    document.getElementById('file').click();
}
```

```html
<body onfocus="myfunction();">
    <input type="file" id="file" />
</body>
```