# How to trigger input file event in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to trigger the *button click* event without having to actually click it. When the page is loaded I want to trigger the click event.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/3vbodd7g/1/)'s the jsfidde link

```
<input type="file" id="test">
    <button>Upload</button>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function (e) {
        $("#test").trigger('click');
    });

    $('button').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: @Pranav: click event is not working!

Comment: simple: you can't show the file browser dialog without the user actually clicking on something. just calling click() on it does nothing without a human-initiated input event.

Comment: I hate to be that guy, but why not use [jQuery File Upload](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)?

Comment: i was trying to use html5 capture camera event. I don't want to click the button every time to take the picture. i was hoping once the picture is taken, i would trigger the camera button event so that user won't have to click on it again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [trigger file upload dialog using javascript/jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502612/trigger-file-upload-dialog-using-javascript-jquery)